# Why error "illegal character: ^M"?

Tags: windows, unix, format, ascii, zsh

I got some sort of formatting -problem that I cannot understand, a short example below using Zsh. Why?

```
$ values=( 300 400 )
$ echo "scale=20; $values[1]-$values[2]" | bc
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^M         // Why does it not print -100?
$ echo $values                                 // no ^M sign found!
300 400
```

**Helper questions**

> 1. Why is `5E 4d 0a`, ie `^M`, 13th char in ASCII?
> 2. Why is the ending sign "0a" shown as a dot "."? The "." is "2E" in Hex.

Comment: You can use `echo -n` to prevent echo from adding a newline at the end of its output, but on my machine this example works just fine, so this is not the problem. Please paste the output of `echo "scale=20; $values[1]-$values[2]" | hexdump -C` and `echo -n "scale=20; $values[1]-$values[2]" | hexdump -C` here.

Comment: `^M` is not the 13th character, it is only its printable representation. `.` in output of `hexdump -C` means both a dot and any unprintable character.

Comment: @ZyX I wish the comments etc were merged into some answer, tried to summarize things to make this thread more readable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unix and Windows have different line ending formats. In the Unix world, lines end with the linefeed character (LF, ascii char 10). Windows ends lines with a carriage return (CR, ascii char 13) followed by a linefeed.

Files with Windows line endings must be converted to Unix format before they can work with Unix tools. Otherwise programs like `bc` see the CR characters as junk and complain, as in your case.

To convert files to Unix format, you can use `dos2unix(1)` if you have it installed, or alternately pass it through `sed 's/^M//g'` (but don't type a literal ^M - press Ctrl+V, followed by Ctrl+M).

So why `^M`? Well, the carriage return is a *nonprintable character*. It has no printable representation. For convenience, your terminal will display it as `^M`*. So why didn't it appear when you did `echo $values`? Unfortunately, the command line argument processing strips it out, so you don't see it.

Also for your convenience, your terminal allows you to *type* nonprintable characters via Ctrl+V and Ctrl + some letter. Ctrl+V and Ctrl+M will produce a `^M` character, but move your cursor left and right and you'll see it skips over the whole thing as a single character - *not* the same as typing `^` followed by `M`. While *you* see `^M`, command line programs see only the raw data, and will see an actual carriage return character.

> Why is 5E 4d 0a, ie ^M, 13th char in ASCII?

You ran `hexdump` on the output of `echo "^M"`, which produces three characters: a `^`, a `M`, and a linefeed character (LF). See above, that's not the same as a carriage return!

> Why is the ending sign 0a shown as .? . is 2E in DEC. Hex number 5E is 94 in DEC, 4d is 77 in DEC.

Hexdump displays all non-printable characters as `.` characters, including carriage return and line feed characters.

---

*Why M in particular? The convention is to add 64 to the ASCII code. A carriage return is ASCII code 13 (0x0D). Add 64 and you get 77 (0x4D) which is an uppercase M. See [this page](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html) for a full listing.

Comment: `<C-v>M` produces `M`, not `^M`. `^M` is produced by `<C-v><C-m>`.

Answer (score 0):

^M in one character - the Carriage Return is dos/windows, or ASCII 13 character. It seems that somehow you compromised your input, maybe by pasting something from a windows file or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck if you run your file through `dos2unix`, if that program is available on your system.

Among other things, `dos2unix` will convert the Windows \r\n line endings to Unix-style \n line endings.

Answer (score 0):

**Answers to Helper Questions**

> **I. Why is 5E 4d 0a, ie ^M, 13th char in ASCII?**
>
> > The newline is the `0a`, please, see the example provided by ZyX below. rjh clarified something about the 13th char. The *"`echo -n` prevents echo from adding a newline at the end of its output"*. I am using Debian.
> >
> > ```
> > $ echo "scale=20; $values[1]-$values[2]" | hexdump -C
> > 00000000  73 63 61 6c 65 3d 32 30  3b 20 5b 31 5d 2d 5b 32  |scale=20; [1]-[2|
> > 00000010  5d 0a                                             |].|
> > 00000012
> > xyz@xyz:~$ echo -n "scale=20; $values[1]-$values[2]" | hexdump -C
> > 00000000  73 63 61 6c 65 3d 32 30  3b 20 5b 31 5d 2d 5b 32  |scale=20; [1]-[2|
> > 00000010  5d                                                |]|
> > 00000011
> > ```
>
> **II. Why is the ending sign "0a" shown as a dot "."? The "." is "2E" in Hex.**
>
> TODO: Did someone answer this already? Please, comment, answer or edit.

**Information to help with the examples**

> **ASCII to HEX**
>
> ```
> `.` is `2E` in Hex
> `5E` is `^` in Hex 
> `4d` is `M` in Hex
> ```
>
> **Hex to ASCII: use this see what the Hex -things mean**
>
> ```
> $ echo "^M" | hexdump -C
> 00000000  5e 4d 0a                                          |^M.|
> 00000003
> $ ascii -x              
>     0 NUL    10 DLE    20      30 0    40 @    50 P    60 `    70 p 
>     1 SOH    11 DC1    21 !    31 1    41 A    51 Q    61 a    71 q 
>     2 STX    12 DC2    22 "    32 2    42 B    52 R    62 b    72 r 
>     3 ETX    13 DC3    23 #    33 3    43 C    53 S    63 c    73 s 
>     4 EOT    14 DC4    24 $    34 4    44 D    54 T    64 d    74 t 
>     5 ENQ    15 NAK    25 %    35 5    45 E    55 U    65 e    75 u 
>     6 ACK    16 SYN    26 &    36 6    46 F    56 V    66 f    76 v 
>     7 BEL    17 ETB    27 '    37 7    47 G    57 W    67 g    77 w 
>     8 BS     18 CAN    28 (    38 8    48 H    58 X    68 h    78 x 
>     9 HT     19 EM     29 )    39 9    49 I    59 Y    69 i    79 y 
>     A LF     1A SUB    2A *    3A :    4A J    5A Z    6A j    7A z 
>     B VT     1B ESC    2B +    3B ;    4B K    5B [    6B k    7B { 
>     C FF     1C FS     2C ,    3C <    4C L    5C \    6C l    7C | 
>     D CR     1D GS     2D -    3D =    4D M    5D ]    6D m    7D } 
>     E SO     1E RS     2E .    3E >    4E N    5E ^    6E n    7E ~ 
>     F SI     1F US     2F /    3F ?    4F O    5F _    6F o    7F DEL
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing this from `~/.gitconfig`

```
[core]
  autocrlf = true
```

Which was appending `^M` to my vim-plug plugins automatically for some reason and breaking neovim.